# Apply a condition to a for loop to plot over all dataframes R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, plot, conditional-statements

I am trying to conditionally output plots based on the values of a factor in multiple dataframes. My dataframes are "n310" and 323 additional dataframes "mrns[[i]]".

I created categories for a variable in the n310 dataframe:

```
n310$ar.cat[n310$arousals_index_per_h_sleep <= 14.9 & n310$arousals_index_per_h_sleep != "NA"] <- "LOW"
n310$ar.cat[n310$arousals_index_per_h_sleep > 14.9 & n310$arousals_index_per_h_sleep < 29.4] <- "MED"
n310$ar.cat[n310$arousals_index_per_h_sleep >= 29.4] <- "HIGH"
```

I added the categorical and continuous variables of n310 to mrns[[i]] by matching to the respective mrn variables:

```
for (i in 1:323) {
  mrns[[i]]$ar.value <- n310$arousals_index_per_h_sleep[match(mrns[[i]]$raw.mrn, n310$mrn)]
  mrns[[i]]$ar.cat <- n310$ar.cat[match(mrns[[i]]$raw.mrn, n310$mrn)]
}
```

Then I tried to plot only the "LOW" category of mrns[[i]]$ar.cat:

```
for (i in 1:323) {
  if (mrns[[i]]$ar.cat == "LOW") {
    png(paste0(arIndLowSys, mrns[[i]]$raw.mrn, "_systolic_ar_index_low.png"), height=1600, width=1600, res=200, family="Times")
    plot(mrns[[i]]$raw.Hour, mrns[[i]]$raw.Systolic, main="Systolic Blood Pressure per Hour of Day", xlab="Hour of Day", ylab="Systolic Blood Pressure", family="Times", bty="L", xlim=c(0, 24), xaxp=c(0, 24, 12))
    mtext(mrns[[i]]$ar.value, side=4, line=0)
    mtext(mrns[[i]]$ar.cat, side=4, line=-1)
    dev.off()
}}
```

And got the following errors:

```
Error in if (mrns[[i]]$ar.cat == "LOW") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

There ARE "NA" or missing values of mrns[[i]]$ar.cat, so I'm not how to disregard those "NA" values when when producing the plots.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: If your 324 datasets are not extremely large don't make your life difficult and instead of having each dataset as a list element create a big dataset with all of them and create a column "dataset id". You can group by this id and apply the same process  to each dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap a `if (!is.na(mrns[[i]]$ar.cat))` around your code so only indices not equal to `NA` are plotted.

```
for (i in 1:323) {
  if (!is.na(mrns[[i]]$ar.cat)) {
        if (mrns[[i]]$ar.cat == "LOW") {
            png(paste0(arIndLowSys, mrns[[i]]$raw.mrn, "_systolic_ar_index_low.png"), height=1600, width=1600, res=200, family="Times")
            plot(mrns[[i]]$raw.Hour, mrns[[i]]$raw.Systolic, main="Systolic Blood Pressure per Hour of Day", xlab="Hour of Day", ylab="Systolic Blood Pressure", family="Times", bty="L", xlim=c(0, 24), xaxp=c(0, 24, 12))
            mtext(mrns[[i]]$ar.value, side=4, line=0)
            mtext(mrns[[i]]$ar.cat, side=4, line=-1)
            dev.off()
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming by the way you've written the question, your data frames are in a list...

You need to use your logical statement as an index:

```
ind = sapply(mrns, function(i){
    which(i$ar.cat == "LOW")
}

for (i in ind) {
    # Your code
}
```

Untested, but you get the idea...

As a comparison, here's how it would look with lapply:

```
lapply(ind, function(i){
    # Your code
})
```

Comment: Thanks @MikeRSpencer! The dataframes are in a list. I just tried to indexing code (with an additional closing parenthesis) and I got the error "Error in mrns[[i]] : invalid subscript type 'list'".

Comment: Oops! Fixed the mistake. I think sapply will run over the list, if not it'll require a little edit.

Comment: Solution was given above, thanks for your time @Mike!

Comment: No worries. Always good to see different ways of doing things.